# How can I access an article directly from its Google AMP page?

Tags: google-search, google-amp

How can I access the actual article page from a [Google AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/) results page?

I did a Google search for "Lego Investment Telegraph", the first result was an AMP page ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyL9W.png)). After loading the AMP page, I could not find a link to load the actual article. Without editing the URL manually, is there any way to access an AMP article without AMP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link to full article is present in the markup of the page but is typically not shown. The following bookmarklet extracts it and directs the browser there.

```
javascript:window.location=document.querySelector("link[rel=canonical]").href
```

To put the bookmarklet in the mobile browser, create a bookmark to whatever page, and then replace the URL with the above (preferably, copy-pasted from this site rather than retyped). If you name the bookmarklet "full", it should be possible to invoke it by typing "full" (or even "fu") in the address bar while you are on an AMP page, and picking the bookmarket from the dropdown with suggestions.

(Bookmarklet written by [Shog9](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/803048538313723910).)

Answer (score 2):

On iOS, hold down the reload button in Safari and choose "Request Desktop Site," and the AMP article will load the original version on the original website.